# Azure AD Authentication redirect NOT to localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, blazor, azure-authentication

### UPDATE 2

After interacting with the Conveyor support service, it looks like it is a problem related to Blazor. By following their instructions on configuring it with Azure by using a normal web app it works fine.

### UPDATE:

It seems to be a problem related to tunneling, by using Conveyor by Keyoti (same problem with Ngrok): even if the URL redirect (e.g. https://mynetcoreapp.conveyor.cloud/signin-oidc) is listed in-app registration in Azure AD the same response is provided. I deployed the project on my public server with its own hostname and it works fine.

---

By following the default tutorial trying to implement login with my tenant Microsoft accounts through Azure AD, i followed the steps listed at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-blazor-server).

I set up the project by using:

```
dotnet new blazorserver -au SingleOrg --client-id "605d0c93-1de4-4c81-99fa-********" --tenant-id "54775aa1-2d0e-48cb-9a7f-*********"
```

It works like charm and logs in users registered in my test Tenant, besides the fact that if I try to redirect not to localhost, for example by using Conveyor Cloud, I get the error:

*AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '605d0c93-1de4-4c81-99fa-a6c3ef2e2b88'.*

with the details:
[image]

This is a public url that I use, just to try if it would work on a public server at production
[image]

This is the default situation, where I have the redirect URL set to localhost.
While it is set with localhost it works, but how to make it work with just the public URL?
[image]

My appconfig.json file works fine with localhost redirect
[image]

What I saw is that even if I also specify the other public URL (from Conveyor) it redirects the wrong way to localhost, and I can imagine that this would not work in a production environment, where I'll have a public hostname. I can't figure out how to set up my project and I know it's probably some dumb configuration stuff, but I'm sorry, I'm a newbie with these technologies.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, the reply URL specified in the request must match the reply URLs configured for the application.

Following this [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-blazor-server), by running `dotnet run --framework netcoreapp3.1`, it runs on `https://localhost:5001` by default. So it works fine because it finds the matched reply URL in your Azure AD app.

Now you only set the reply URL in your Azure AD application. But you didn't configure the matched reply URL in your Blazor Server app side.

Don't worry about that because if you publish your Blazor Server app into Azure cloud, it will configure that part for you automatically. The only thing you need to do is to configure the  Blazor Server app url (`https://blaz-aad.conveyor.cloud/signin-oidc`) into Azure AD app.

If you want to know why it uses 5001 port in your local environment, you can see the configuration in `BlazorSample\Properties\launchSettings.json` file.

```
"BlazorSample": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

`"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"` matches the redirect URL you configured in the Azure AD app.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The thing is that I'll publish my Blazor Server app on a on-premise server with its own public hostname. Sorry but I didn't get your answer, I still can't redirect correctly if I don't use https://localhost:44378/signin-oidc. Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: @exrezzo OK. Then try to configure `launchSettings.json` file.